# Managing resources (database, elasticsearch, redis, etc) for tests using Docker and Jenkins

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, jenkins, docker, redis

We need to use Jenkins to test some web apps that each need:

- a database (postgres in our case)
- a search service (ElasticSearch in our case, but only sometimes)
- a cache server, such as redis

So far, we've just had these services running on the Jenkins master, but this causes problems when we want to upgrade Postgres, ES or Redis versions. Not all apps can move in lock step, and we want to run the tests on new versions before committing to move an app in production.

What we'd like to do is have these services provided on a per-job-run basis, each one running in its own container.

What's the best way to orchestrate these containers?

- How do you start up these ancillary containers and tear them down, regardless of whether to job succeeds or not?
- how do you prevent port collisions between, say, the database in a run of a job for one web app and the database in the job for another web app?

Answer (score 2):

Check [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and write a docker-compose file for your tests.
The [latest network features](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) of Docker (private network) will help you to isolate builds running in parallel.

However, start learning docker-compose as if you only had one build at the same time. When confident with this, look further for advanced docker documentation around networking.

Comment: This is, of course, the "correct" answer, but we're stuck on Docker 1.8, and the features you're referring to need a newer version of the docker api to work.

What are the other options?

Comment: 'Ancestor' of network was 'links'. You should be able to 'link'all the containers for a single job. To be able to execute multiple jobs in parallel, I would work on giving dynamic names of the links (ex: a script generates a docker-compose yml file with unique links names). This would be a trick while waiting for a Docker upgrade on your machines.